# If $A, B, C$ are subsets of $S$ and $A\subseteq C$, prove $B \cup C = A \cup B \cup C$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If $A, B, C$ are subsets of $S$ and $A\subseteq C$, prove $B \cup C = A \cup B \cup C$.

I know this is relatively straightforward but I was looking for some direction on how to approach this proof. I'm initially attempting a direct proof but could use other's thoughts as well.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to typeset maths here with MathJax and $\LaTeX$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks, this is my first post here so I appreciate you letting me know

Comment: As for what you can do... just note that $A\subseteq C$ implies that $A\cup C = C$.  Make sure you understand this and have either proven it before or have been shown this proof before in your book/notes/earlier exercises (*otherwise, show it here as well as a substep of the proof*).  You have then $A\cup B\cup C = B\cup (A\cup C) = B\cup C$ completing the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Lemma:** For sets $A$ and $C$, we have that $A\subseteq C$ implies $C=A\cup C.$

*Proof:* Let $x\in C$. Then, surely, since either $x\in C$ or $x\in A$, we have $x\in A\cup C$. Hence $C\subseteq A\cup C$. Now let $x\in A\cup C$. Then we have two cases: (1) $x\in A$, in which case, since $A\subseteq C$, $x\in C$; or (2) $x\in C$. In both cases, $x\in C$. Hence $A\cup C\subseteq C$. Hence $C=A\cup C$ by double inclusion. $\square$

Now, since taking the union of sets is both commutative and associative, we have

$$\begin{align}
A\cup B\cup C&=(A\cup B)\cup C\\
&=(B\cup A)\cup C\\
&=B\cup (A\cup C)\\
&=B\cup C.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Proposition : $ A \subseteq A \cup B $

Proof:
Assume $ x \in A$.

By Addition, $x \in A \lor x \in B$.

By definition, $x \in A \cup B$.

Thus,. $A \subseteq A \cup B$.

Theorem: $A \subseteq C$ implies $A \cup B \cup C = B \cup C$

Proof:
It is easy to see, $B \cup C \subseteq A \cup B \cup C$.

Now, let $x \in A \cup B \cup C$.

Thus, $x \in A \lor x \in B \lor x \in C$ ...(1)

Also we know, $A \subseteq C$

Thus, $ x \in A$ implies $x \in C$

Thus, $x \notin A \lor x \in C$ ... (2)

By Resolution of (1) and (2),

$x \in B \lor x \in C \lor x \in C$

Thus, $x \in B \lor x \in C$

Thus, $x \in B \cup C$

Hence, $A \cup B \cup C \subseteq B \cup C$

Thus, we have "proved" $A \cup B \cup C = B \cup C$